# SqlAlchemy. Return of previous data after the update

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, select-for-update

It is necessary to write a query on SQLAlchemy objects to return the previous values after the update.Postgresql

The following table is available:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('\"public\".users_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    last_name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    first_name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

I need to return the previous data after the update. The raw query looks like this

```
update
    users x
        set
            email = 'example@example.com'
        from
            (
            select
                *
            from
                users
            where
                id = 1 for update) y
        where
            x.id = y.id
        returning 
            y.*
```

An attempt to write something like this was unsuccessful

```
old_user: User = aliased(User, name='old_user')

update_stmt = update(User) \
    .where(user_old.id == User.id) \
    .where(User.id == 1) \
    .values(email = "example@example.com") \
    .returning(old_user)

return session.execute(update_stmt)
```

An error occurs
`sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: Could not locate column in row for column 'old_user.id'`

But if you try to return a non-alias object, then an object with new values is returned.

Also, an attempt to return(text(public.old_user.*)) causes an error
`NotImplementedError`

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** directly do what you are wanting. Once updated the only way to get the old value is having archived it to another table, or to rollback the update. There is however a workaround (not necessary a good one). Postgres allows a CTE to contain DML. So create 2 CTEs, the first retrieves the old data, the second does the update, and finally the main query retrieves the first CTE: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/StMCMlPP))

```
with old_row as 
     ( select email   
         from users 
        where id = 1
      ) 
   , new_row as 
     ( update users 
          set email = 'example@example.com'
        where id=1
     ) 
select * 
  from old_row;
```

Sorry, I do not know your obscurification language (SQLAlchemy) so I leave the translation into it to you you.

Comment: Your version of raw sql will work the same way as mine. Return the previous line.
But the question was precisely the translation of this query into the form of SQLAlchemy (python sql orm).

Comment: The crux of the matter is sqlalchemy does not return the alias of the saved string.
2 separate queries are not suitable for solving this problem, as well as the actual use of a raw query.
Thanks for the answer